# Why can't I pass a Protocol.Type to a generic T.Type parameter?

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I was working with Swinject and a problem is bugging me. I have been stuck one this for almost an entire day. I suspect this is due to Swift being a statictly typed language but I'm not entirely sure.

I summarized my problem in this playground

```
protocol Protocol {}

class Class: Protocol {}

let test: Protocol.Type = Class.self

func printType(confromingClassType: Protocol.Type) {
    print(confromingClassType)
}

func printType<Service>(serviceType: Service.Type) {
    print(serviceType)
}

print(Class.self) // "Class"
printType(serviceType: Class.self) // "Class"
print(test) // "Class"
printType(confromingClassType: test) // "Class"

printType(serviceType: test) // "note: expected an argument list of type '(serviceType: Service.Type)'"
```

I tried different solutions like test.self or type(of: test) but none of them work.

So I guess I can't call a function with a generic parameter provided as a variable ?

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to do?

Comment: Are you trying to have a function that accepts a Class instance as a parameter, in other words Swift equivalent of Java's `String myFunc(Class<?> classInstance)`

Comment: The problem you're facing is that with a generic placeholder `T`, when `T` is a protocol `P`, `T.Type` is `P.Protocol` (metatype that describes the protocol itself) and *not* `P.Type` (metatype that describes a concrete type that conforms to `P`). What's the concrete problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: I'm not sure to completely understand what you mean. My example should work. I can call `printType(confromingClassType: )` the only difference is the genericity of the type Service

Comment: @GuillaumeL. You can call `printType(confromingClassType:)` with an argument of `test` because it has a parameter of type `Protocol.Type`. `printType(serviceType:)` has *no such* parameter. As said, a `T.Type` parameter for a generic placeholder `T` cannot accept an existential metatype (`P.Type` for some protocol `P`). If it did, you would be unable to say `printType(serviceType: Protocol.self)`, as a `P.Protocol` is not a `P.Type`. Again, what's the *actual* problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: "As said, a T.Type parameter for a generic placeholder T cannot accept an existential metatype (P.Type for some protocol P)." Why it doesn't ? It is a generic type, that's the point of it, being generic !
What I'm trying to do here is calling the function `printType(serviceType:)` with only classes that I know are implementing Protocol.

Comment: @GuillaumeL. "*What I'm trying to do here is calling the function `printType(serviceType:)` with only classes that I know are implementing Protocol*" – then you want a `Protocol.Type` parameter, exactly as you have with `printType(confromingClassType:)`. Generics aren't compatible with what you're trying to achieve; what would you expect `Service.self` to be? If you expect `T.Type` to be `P.Type` when `T` is some protocol `P`, `Service.self` cannot be `Protocol.self`. Why? Because `Protocol.self` is of type `Protocol.Protocol`, not `Protocol.Type`, and your rules said that `T.Type` is `P.Type`

Comment: _"What I'm trying to do here is calling the function printType(serviceType:) with only classes **TYPES** that I know are implementing Protocol"_ Sorry I mistyped my answer

Comment: @GuillaumeL. I wrote an answer hopefully illustrating why `T.Type` must be `P.Protocol`, and not `P.Type` :) Let me know if you need any further clarification

Answer (score 40, accepted):

#### `P.Type` vs. `P.Protocol`

There are two kinds of protocol metatypes. For some protocol `P`, and a conforming type `C`:

- A `P.Protocol` describes the type of a protocol itself (the only value it can hold is `P.self`).
- A `P.Type` describes a concrete type that conforms to the protocol. It can hold a value of `C.self`, but *not* `P.self` because [protocols don't conform to themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43408193/2976878) (although one exception to this rule is `Any`, as `Any` is the [top type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_type), so any metatype value can be typed as `Any.Type`; including `Any.self`).

The problem you're facing is that for a given generic placeholder `T`, when `T` is some protocol `P`, `T.Type` is *not* `P.Type` – it is `P.Protocol`.

So if we jump back to your example:

```
protocol P {}
class C : P {}

func printType<T>(serviceType: T.Type) {
    print(serviceType)
}

let test: P.Type = C.self

// Cannot invoke 'printType' with an argument list of type '(serviceType: P.Type)'
printType(serviceType: test)
```

We cannot pass `test` as an argument to `printType(serviceType:)`. Why? Because `test` is a `P.Type`; and there's no substitution for `T` that makes the `serviceType:` parameter take a `P.Type`.

If we substitute in `P` for `T`, the parameter takes a `P.Protocol`:

```
printType(serviceType: P.self) // fine, P.self is of type P.Protocol, not P.Type
```

If we substitute in a *concrete* type for `T`, such as `C`, the parameter takes a `C.Type`:

```
printType(serviceType: C.self) // C.self is of type C.Type
```

---

#### Hacking around with protocol extensions

Okay, so we've learnt that if we can substitute in a *concrete* type for `T`, we can pass a `C.Type` to the function. Can we substitute in the dynamic type that the `P.Type` wraps? Unfortunately, this requires a language feature called [opening existentials](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md#opening-existentials), which currently isn't directly available to users.

However, Swift *does* implicitly open existentials when accessing members on a protocol-typed instance or metatype (i.e it digs out the runtime type and makes it accessible in the form of a generic placeholder). We can take advantage of this fact in a protocol extension:

```
protocol P {}
class C : P {}

func printType<T>(serviceType: T.Type) {
  print("T.self = \(T.self)")
  print("serviceType = \(serviceType)")
}

extension P {
  static func callPrintType/*<Self : P>*/(/*_ self: Self.Type*/) {
    printType(serviceType: self)
  }
}

let test: P.Type = C.self
test.callPrintType()
// T.self = C
// serviceType = C
```

There's quite a bit of stuff going on here, so let's unpack it a little bit:

- The extension member `callPrintType()` on `P` has an implicit generic placeholder `Self` that's constrained to `P`. The implicit `self` parameter is typed using this placeholder.
- When calling `callPrintType()` on a `P.Type`, Swift implicitly digs out the dynamic type that the `P.Type` wraps (this is the opening of the existential), and uses it to satisfy the `Self` placeholder. It then passes this dynamic metatype to the implicit `self` parameter.
- So, `Self` will be satisfied by `C`, which can then be forwarded onto `printType`'s generic placeholder `T`.

---

#### Why is `T.Type` not `P.Type` when `T == P`?

You'll notice how the above workaround works because we avoided substituting in `P` for the generic placeholder `T`. But why when substituting in a protocol type `P` for `T`, is `T.Type` *not* `P.Type`?

Well, consider:

```
func foo<T>(_: T.Type) {
    let t: T.Type = T.self
    print(t)
}
```

What if we substituted in `P` for `T`? If `T.Type` is `P.Type`, then what we've got is:

```
func foo(_: P.Type) {
    // Cannot convert value of type 'P.Protocol' to specified type 'P.Type'
    let p: P.Type = P.self
    print(p)
}
```

which is illegal; we cannot assign `P.self` to `P.Type`, as it's of type `P.Protocol`, not `P.Type`.

So, the upshot is that if you want a function parameter that takes a metatype describing *any* concrete type that conforms to `P` (rather than just one specific concrete conforming type) – you just want a `P.Type` parameter, not generics. Generics don't model heterogenous types, that's what protocol types are for.

And that's exactly what you have with `printType(conformingClassType:)`:

```
func printType(conformingClassType: P.Type) {
    print(conformingClassType)
}

printType(conformingClassType: test) // okay
```

You can pass `test` to it because it has a parameter of type `P.Type`. But you'll note this now means we cannot pass `P.self` to it, as it is not of type `P.Type`:

```
// Cannot convert value of type 'P.Protocol' to expected argument type 'P.Type'
printType(conformingClassType: P.self)
```

Comment: Thank you for your very complete answer, it's not trivial to say the least. So I guess I can't do what I wanted to do, which is a bit sad. Do you think there is a work around or something that should be done in a different way to make that possible ?

Comment: @GuillaumeL. I do agree that the current state of metatypes are far from ideal, and I fully expect them to be overhauled in a future version of the language. Unfortunately, I'm not at all familiar with Swinject, so cannot suggest a current workaround to your problem (I don't know what the metatype parameter is used for). It may well be worth asking a new question focussing on what you're trying to achieve with Swinject (you can always link back to this question for context); and hopefully someone familiar with the framework could offer you a workaround.

Comment: @GuillaumeL. Just thought of a workaround using a little known trick with protocol extensions; might be useful for you.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the update. I had to read my question again to remember what I was talking about. Since then we gave up on this idea but maybe we could try again with your workaround !

Answer (score 1):

I've ran your code in a playground, and it seems that this is the reason why it wont compile

```
let test: Protocol.Type = Class.self
```

If you remove the type declaration for `test`, the code will work and will print out `Class.Type` at line `15`.

So the following code compiles and runs:

```
protocol Protocol {}

class Class: Protocol {}

let test = Class.self

func printType<Service>(serviceType: Service.Type) {
    print(serviceType)
}

print(Class.Type.self) // "Class.Type"
printType(serviceType: Class.Type.self) // "Class.Type"
print(type(of: test)) // "Class.Type"

printType(serviceType: type(of: test)) // "Class.Type"
```

I hope this helps with your problem.

---

**Edit**

The error I am getting in the playground with the original code is the following:

```
Playground execution failed: error: Untitled Page 2.xcplaygroundpage:9:1: error: cannot invoke 'printType' with an argument list of type '(serviceType: Protocol.Type.Type)'
printType(serviceType: type(of: test)) // "Class.Type"
```

This means you are calling `Type` 2 times, that's why the code will not compile, because the type you are already calling the method with the argument of type `Protocol.Type`.

If you change the method's signature like this:

let test: Protocol.Type = Class.self

```
func printType<Service>(serviceType: Service) {
    print(serviceType)
}
```

everything will compile and work right, printing `Class.type`

This is also the reason my first version of the answer will compile, since it will assign the right type for `test` can call `.Type` only once.

Comment: I am curious about what actually prevented this `let test: Protocol.Type = Class.self`

Comment: It's a nice try but it doesn't really solve the problem because in the app we don't know the type of test, the only thing we know is that it conforms to a protocol. That's why test must be implementing the protocol to reflect the real case.

Comment: I can't change the function signature, it's a function from the Swinject framework

`public func register<Service, Arg1>(
    _ serviceType: Service.Type, 
    name: String? = nil, 
    factory: @escaping (Resolver, Arg1) -> Service) -> ServiceEntry<Service>`