# Passing a type variable as a parameter in Swift

Tags: swift

I have a method with signature:

```
func relatedObject<T: SomeType>(for type: T.Type) -> SomeRelatedObject
```

I have a `SomeType.Type` variable, and I want to call the method somehow, like:

```
let typeVariable: SomeType.Type = ...
let result = relatedObject(for: typeVariable)
```

but I get an error:

```
Cannot invoke 'relatedObject' with an argument list of type '(for: SomeType.Type)'
```

Is it possible to actually invoke the method somehow having a type variable?

Comment: Is `SomeType` a protocol? (if it's a concrete type, your code should work). Compare [Why can't I pass a Protocol.Type to a generic T.Type parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45234233/2976878)

Comment: That's true, it is a protocol. Thanks! Didn't know there is a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call it like this

```
relatedObject(for: SomeType.self)
```

Here instead of SomeType you can pass any class/struct that conforms to  SomeType. Lets say your CustomClass conforms to SomeType then you can pass it like

```
relatedObject(for: CustomClass.self)
```

Comment: But OP wants to pass a `SomeType.Type` to the function, not a `SomeType.Protocol` (which is what `SomeType.self` is in this case).