# Pass AnyObject as generic T parameter in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift4

I have an interesting problem:

```
class ListCache {

    public func getCachedList<T: Codable>() -> [T]? {
        //loads list from file cache using Codable
    }

}
```

let's say I have class Foo:

```
class Foo: Codable {
    var bar = ""
}
```

Now, I can do something like this:

```
let array: [Foo] = ListCache().getCachedList()
```

but I cannot do something like this:

```
var listsToLoad: [AnyClass] = [Foo.self]
let clazz = listsToLoad[0]
let array: [Codable] = ListCache().getCachedList()
```

Compiler gives me an error:

> Cannot explicitly specialize a generic function

This means I cannot call `getCachedList()` in a loop because I have to explicitly give it a class type.

Is there a way to achieve this? I've also tried using generic classes, but I pretty much end in the same point.

Edit:

I've tried creating:

```
class CodableClass: Codable {

}
```

then:

```
class Foo: CodableClass {
    //...
}
```

and now compiler says clazz is undeclared:

```
var listsToLoad: [CodableClass.Type] = [Foo.self]
for clazz in listsToLoad {
    if let array: [clazz] = ListCache().getCachedList() {
        print(array.count)
    }
}
```

I've tried `clazz.Type` and `clazz.self` as well.

Comment: Why do yo need to use generics here? Can't you just use `public func getCachedList() -> [Codable]?`. I dont really understand what you are doing in that last block of code. `var listsToLoad: [AnyClass] = [Foo.self]` doesn't make sense to me, the assignment looks more like a type definition?

Comment: That's because in getCachedList I load json from file and using Codable I'm converting it to [T] array.

Comment: You are trying to create array of Codable object by `let array: [Codable] = ListCache().getCachedList()`. but protocal 'Codable' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers.

Comment: Is there a way to use different thing than Codable to use array like this?

Comment: Another suggestion would be: Stop implementing a cache by yourself and let [URLCache](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlcache) do all the work. In your requests you can specify the caching strategy and your server could add `Cache-Control` information in the response header.

Comment: What's the reason for the array? I'm not sure what you're trying to solve by introducing it (over just requesting with the concrete type when you need them).

Comment: @fl034 I cannot change server. Oliver Atkinson Just for less code, because everything is repeating, just class changes.

Comment: The value stored in `clazz` is determined at runtime, while generics need to be resolved at compile time, meaning you cannot use the contents of a variable to call a generic function.

Comment: I mean, you *could* hack this [with a protocol extension](https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/6473352f5891c2bf8be60307e2755645) (compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/45234233/2976878). But what would you do with the resulting `[Decodable]`? You'd need to do some type casting to concrete type(s); so why not decode with those concrete type(s) to begin with?

Answer (score 4):

I'm fairly certain that in order to call a generic function, that function's parameter types have to be known at compile time. And since `[Foo]` is really just a shorthand for `Array<Foo>`, that applies to typed arrays, too (try writing `Array<clazz>`; it won't compile). So when you have a type in a `clazz` variable, such that the actual class is only known at runtime, you can't use it to call generic functions, nor can you declare an array typed to that class.

AFAIK, the only solutions are to:

1. Find a way to do what you're trying to do dynamically, Objective-C-style, using `[Codable]`, or:
2. Find another way to do what you're trying to do :-(

Since I don't know what it is that you're ultimately trying to do, it's hard to go too far beyond that, unfortunately.

Comment: In "real" app I have several lists downloaded from an external server when the app starts. However, using Codable, I wanted to cache these lists and don't always download them. So, I wanted to create an Array of classes, pass it to the function, which will load from cache and if it's not possible or data is too old will download it from an external server. I didn't want to copy-paste all code, but rather do this nicely in an array.

Comment: @Makalele You could define an enum with a case for each data source, and just switch over the enum, calling `getCachedList()` using the appropriate static type. It's not quite as tidy as generic code, but it should work.

Comment: The same way I do this now: instead of enum I just if-check for each type. That's basically the same :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try following

```
class ListCache {

  public func getCachedList<T: Cachable>() -> [T] {
    return [(Foo() as! T)]
  }

}

protocol Cachable: Codable { }

class CachableClass: Cachable {
  class func test() -> String {
    return "blo"
  }
}

extension Cachable {

  static func cachedValues() -> [Self] {
    return cachedValuesTemplate(type: self)
  }

  private static func cachedValuesTemplate<T: Cachable>(type: T.Type) -> [T] {
    return ListCache().getCachedList()
  }

}

class Foo: CachableClass { }

var listsToLoad: [CachableClass.Type] = [Foo.self]
for clazz in listsToLoad {
  print(clazz.cachedValues().count)
}
```

Comment: This implementation won't work with structures though.

Comment: @Misternewb I see only classes in the question.

Comment: For some reason after creating Foo() item I wanted to change it's property (now I named it var fastTest = "") I'm getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash. Why?

Comment: If I remove "CachableClass" from Foo the crash does not occur.

Comment: @Makalele have you changed `return [(Foo() as! T)]` line to your implementation?

Comment: Yes. Here I've uploaded the sample project: http://www81.zippyshare.com/v/GOTAmzB1/file.html

Comment: @Makalele post minimum code with reproducible issue for Playgrounds.

Comment: @Makalele looks like it's caused by Codable and class inheritance. You can try implementing Codable protocol on your own.

Comment: @Makalele You should add the link to the sample project with the question so that everybody will be able to see it.