# How to iterate over an array of types in Swift 4.1?

Tags: swift, conditional-statements, protocols

I'm using **Xcode 9.4.1** with **Swift 4.1** on **iOS 11.4.1**.

I've got a handful of protocols, like this:

```
protocol Bla {
    // some stuff
}

protocol Gorp {
    // some other stuff
}
```

And I've got some structs that conform to both of those protocols, like this:

```
typealias MyType = Bla & Gorp

struct Hello: MyType {
    var ID: Int
    var name: String
}

struct Goodbye: MyType {
    var percentage: Double
    var hairbrush: String
}
```

Then I've got a func that takes an argument, **theType**, which conforms to both **Bla & Gorp**.  In this example, I'm just printing a description -- like this:

```
func doSomething<T: MyType>(_ theType: T.Type) {
    // some stuff
    print("Got called... \(theType)")
}
```

And, I can call this function passing each of the two struct types (**Hello** and **Goodbye**), like this:

```
doSomething(Hello.self)
doSomething(Goodbye.self)
```

This works great and I get the following output, as expected:

```
Got called... Hello
Got called... Goodbye
```

However, what I'd really like to do is to iterate over a bunch of these, rather than calling them individually.

This way gives me an error "*note: expected an argument list of type '(T.Type)'*":

```
for thingy in [Hello.self, Goodbye.self] {
    doSomething(thingy)
}
```

If I add an **as! [MyType.Type]** or **as! [MyType]**, I get the same error.  I've also tried this:

```
for thingy in [Hello.self as MyType.Type, Goodbye.self as MyType.Type]  {
    doSomething(thingy)
}
```

Same error as the rest.

I've also tried without the **typealias**.

If I start typing, the autocomplete says that **doSomething** is expecting an argument of type **(Bla & Gorp).Protocol**.  So, I also tried this:

```
for thingy in [Hello.self, Goodbye.self] as! [(Bla & Gorp).Protocol]  {
    doSomething(thingy)
}
```

In this case, I get the message:

```
In argument type '(Bla & Gorp).Protocol', 'Bla & Gorp' does not conform to expected type 'Bla'
```

Also tried this sort of thing, which gave an error, "*Cannot invoke 'doSomething' with an argument list of type '(MyType.Type)'*":

```
struct AnyBlaGorp {
    let blaGorp: MyType.Type

    init<T: MyType>(_ theType: T.Type) {
        self.blaGorp = theType
    }
}

for thingy in [AnyBlaGorp(Hello.self), AnyBlaGorp(Goodbye.self)]  {
    doSomething(thingy.blaGorp)
}
```

Pointers to the magical correct syntax would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Is there any associated types or `Self` in the protocols?

Comment: No there aren't -- I'm using them exactly like in the example given.

Comment: `for thingy in [Hello.self, Goodbye.self] {
    doSomething(thingy)
}` can't work because Swift is a compiled language.  At compile time it needs to know which `doSomething` it is calling on that line of code.

Comment: Compare [Why can't I pass a Protocol.Type to a generic T.Type parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45234233/2976878)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the `doSomething` method non-generic and accept a `MyType.Type`. You can only do this if your protocols don't have `Self` or associated types.

```
func doSomething(_ theType: MyType.Type) {
    // some stuff
    print("Got called... \(theType)")
}
```

Next, you cast the array to a `[MyType.Type]`:

```
for thingy in [Hello.self, Goodbye.self] as [MyType.Type] {
    doSomething(thingy)
}
```

This makes use of the fact that `A.self` can be converted to the type `B.Type` if `A` inherits from/conforms to `B`.

Comment: SUPER awesome!!  Somehow it never occurred to me to do away with the generic.