# Why protocol's existential metatype looses inheritance information?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, protocols

I have a generic function where I am passing `protocol` type and based on the passed type I am returning a required `struct`. If I put a protocol constraint on the generic even if the passed protocol conforms to it I am getting an error.

```
protocol BaseProtocol {}

protocol ProtocolA: BaseProtocol {}
protocol ProtocolB: BaseProtocol {}

struct StructA: ProtocolA {}
struct StructB: ProtocolB {}
```

When I define my function with a constraint like this:

```
func getStruct<T: BaseProtocol>(type: T.Type) -> T {
   switch type {
   case is ProtocolA.Protocol:
       return StructA() as! T
   case is ProtocolB.Protocol:
       return StructB() as! T
   default:
       fatalError("Unknown Type")
   }
}

let result = getStruct(type: ProtocolA.self)
print(type(of: result))
```

It does not work and generates the following error:

[image: xcode error]

If I remove the BaseProtocol constraint all works fine:

```
func getStruct<T: Any>(type: T.Type) -> T {
   switch type {
   case is ProtocolA.Protocol:
       return StructA() as! T
   case is ProtocolB.Protocol:
       return StructB() as! T
   default:
       fatalError("Unknown Type")
   }
}
```

Is there any other way to put that constraint? Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: That's because in Swift protocols don't conform to parent protocols

Comment: More info about the above, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43408193/1974224

Comment: not an answer to your question but have you thought about creating an extension to your protocol that implements that method in combination with the type(of:)?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you don't get a protocol type in your `getStruct` method's `type` parameter. You get a `struct`, `enum` or `class` that conform `BaseProtocol`

You can look this for more information:
[Answer of: Why can't I pass a Protocol.Type to a generic T.Type parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45239416/6608199)