# How to specify generic type as variable?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function inside a model class that uses the following generic:

```
func loadNextPage<T: ListDiffable & JSONDecodable>(as: T.Type)
```

I call this function from my view controller like this:

```
model.loadNextPage(as: EventJSONModel.self)
```

However, because my view controller can be used to load data of different types, I need to specify `T.Type` on load of the view controller. My view controller can't be instantiated as a generic though as I'm loading it through the storyboard.

Ideally I'd like to create a variable like:

```
private var objectType: (ListDiffable & JSONDecodable).Type = EventJSONModel.self
```

Then reference it like this:

```
model.loadNextPage(as: objectType)
```

But this doesn't work... How can I do this?

Comment: "My view controller can't be instantiated as a generic though as I'm loading it through the storyboard.". This is possible with a protocol

Comment: @J.Doe What do you mean?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `typealias` here? Instead of variable-with-type. Also `ListDiffable & JSONDecodable` and `T: ListDiffable & JSONDecodable` is not the same. Former is `protocol` combining two protocols, latter is some type implementing both of protocols.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing Protocol.Type to generic T.Type, which cannot be done directly. There are some hacks around though.
Check out this thread.
[Why can't I pass a Protocol.Type to a generic T.Type parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45234233/why-cant-i-pass-a-protocol-type-to-a-generic-t-type-parameter)