# Behavior of Swift Any.Type and generics

Tags: swift, generics, metatype

Given a function with a generic parameter, I would like to pass a value of which type is `Any.Type` to the function but it doesn't compile.

```swift
func foo<T>(_ type: T.Type) {
    print(type)
}

foo(Any.self) // ok
foo(Int.self) // ok

let a: Any.Type = Any.self // ok
let b: Any.Type = Int.self // ok

foo(a) // error: expected an argument list of type '(T.Type)'
foo(b) // error: expected an argument list of type '(T.Type)'
```

My assumption is that:

1. `foo(Any.self)` successfully compiles and the type placeholder `T` would hold `Any`.
2. Similarly, if a value of type `Any.Type` is given, the `T` should be resolved into `Any`

Could you explain why this code doesn't work?

Comment: See [Why can't I pass a Protocol.Type to a generic T.Type parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45234233/2976878) – for `foo(Any.self)`, `Any.self` is treated as `Any.Protocol` allowing the code to compile.

Comment: @Hamish Thank you for the link! It really helped me understand how it works.