# Swift Generic Protocol Class Type in Array

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols

We have implemented a protocol, `Reusable`, to ease `UITableView` register/dequeue implementations, for our `UITableViewCell`s.

```
protocol Reusable: class {
    static var defaultIdentifier: String { get }
}

extension Reusable where Self: UITableViewCell {
    static var defaultIdentifier: String {
        return String(describing: self)
    }
}

class TestTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, Reusable { }
class AnotherTestTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, Reusable { }
```

Then, there's an extension to `UITableView` like:

```
extension UITableView {
    func register<T: UITableViewCell & Reusable>(_: T.Type) {
        register(UINib(nibName: T.defaultIdentifier, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: T.defaultIdentifier)
    }
}
```

and as its usage:

```
let tableView: UITableView = UITableView()
tableView.register(TestTableViewCell.self)
tableView.register(AnotherTableViewCell.self)
```

Everything works well, but we'd like to move these types to an array, for order. That's where we're stuck, this doesn't work:

```
let viewCells = [TestTableViewCell.self, AnotherTestTableViewCell.self]
// Without type annotation, it's [UITableViewCell.Type]
// And the error is: Instance method 'register' requires that 'UITableViewCell' conform to 'Reusable'

for viewCell in viewCells {
    tableView.register(viewCell)
}
```

We've also tried:

```
let viewCells: [Reusable.Type] = ...
// Error: Cannot invoke 'register' with an argument list of type '(Reusable.Type)'
```

Also this:

```
let viewCells: [(UITableViewCell & Reusable).Type] = ...
// Error: Instance method 'register' requires that 'UITableViewCell' conform to 'Reusable'
```

Is there a way to store the class type info with protocol conformance in an array to make this work?

Comment: What's version of Swift are you using?

Comment: @Vyacheslav 4.2

Comment: What's the problem? It doesn't compile? I tried in playground and it compiles

Comment: @RicoCrescenzio yes, I've edited the question, it's because there's only 1 type of class type in the array. It should not compile.

Comment: "but we'd like to move these types to an array” You’re going to have trouble doing that. Swift doesn’t like the notion of an array of metatypes; a metatype is not really a type in Swift. You might be happier using some other programming language, or some other approach to the overall goal.

Comment: @matt My thanks for the info, it's not a showstopper but it'd be nice to have, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just write an extension for `UITableViewCell` so it conforms to `Reusable` protocol and do not cast cells to any type:

```
extension UITableViewCell: Reusable {}
```

---

P.S. you can also check the most popular `Reusable` protocol implementation on iOS [here](https://github.com/AliSoftware/Reusable/tree/master/Sources/View).

---

Good luck :)

Comment: It doesn't work unfortunately: `Value of type ‘UITableViewCell.Type’ does not conform to ‘UITableViewCell & Reusable’ in coercion`

Comment: Instead of discussing in comments lets have a [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192054/room-for-tomas-jablonskis-and-edusta).

Comment: Summary of chat: It works, but we'd really like not to extend the protocol to every `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: @EDUsta Why don't you want to extend every `UITableViewCell` to conform to the protocol?

Comment: @JeremyP Fair question, there are some `UITableViewCell` classes that doesn't have a separate nib, or doesn't match with their names, so we're not ready to make that transition yet, instead we're doing one-by-one and get to know the process (which cells are ready/not ready).

Comment: @EDUsta In that case, why not just extend the subclasses of UITableViewCell that you are OK with?

Comment: @JeremyP Do you mean as a superclass? If so, I wouldn't prefer that. Anyways, the main point in the question is that how can we hold on to the class type in an array. Do you have an idea over that, or is it not possible?

Comment: @EDUsta No, I mean add `Reusable` conformance to each specific subclass. If you have an extension on `Reusable` to add a default implementation of `defaultIdentifier`, the work is minimal.

Comment: @JeremyP Indeed, we did that exactly as per the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
protocol Reusable: class {
    static var defaultIdentifier: String { get }
}

extension Reusable where Self: UITableViewCell {
    static var defaultIdentifier: String {
        return String(describing: self)
    }
}

class TestTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, Reusable { }
extension UITableView {
    func register<T: UITableViewCell & Reusable>(_: T.Type) {
        register(UINib(nibName: T.defaultIdentifier, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: T.defaultIdentifier)
    }
}
let tableView: UITableView = UITableView()
tableView.register(TestTableViewCell.self)
let viewCells = [TestTableViewCell.self]
// Without type annotation, it's [UITableViewCell.Type]
// And the error is: Instance method 'register' requires that 'UITableViewCell' conform to 'Reusable'

for viewCell in viewCells {
    tableView.register(viewCell)
}
```

This code successfully executes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I couldn't see any difference, is it about Swift 4.2/5?

Comment: Update: When there's only 1 class, it compiles, but if there's more, it doesn't. Updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are happy with this. The key is `Self` keyword in protocol.

```
protocol Reusable: class {
    static var defaultIdentifier: String { get }
    static func register(tableView: UITableView)
}

extension Reusable where Self: UITableViewCell {
    static var defaultIdentifier: String {
        return String(describing: self)
    }

    static func register(tableView: UITableView) {
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: Self.defaultIdentifier, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: Self.defaultIdentifier)
    }
}

extension UITableView {
    func register(_ reusable: Reusable.Type) {
        reusable.register(tableView: self)
    }
}
```

```
let viewCells: [Reusable.Type] = [TestTableViewCell.self, AnotherTestTableViewCell.self]

for viewCell in viewCells {
    tableView.register(viewCell)
}
```

I recommend you to read the following links:

- [Known issues of metatypes](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0126-refactor-metatypes-repurpose-t-dot-self-and-mirror.md#known-issues-of-metatypes)
- [Why can't I pass a Protocol.Type to a generic T.Type parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45239416/1556838)
- [Metatype Type on Language Reference](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Types.html#grammar_metatype-type)

Comment: @EDUsta Sounds great. Please accept my answer if you don't mind

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this table view extension method to register the cell.

```
 extension UITableView {
     func registerCell<T: UITableViewCell>(cellType: T.Type) {
        let nib = UINib(nibName: String(describing: cellType.self), bundle: nil)
        let reuseIdentifier = String(describing: cellType.self)
        self.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
     }
}
```

And use it like so

```
 let tableView: UITableView = UITableView()
    let cellsArray = [Test.self, Test1.self, Test2.self]
    for cell in cellsArray {
        tableView.registerCell(cellType: cell)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it just ignores the protocol and that's the whole reason we're doing this.